# ValueError: array length 3 does not match index length 7488

Tags: python

Hi I am coming across a value error that is blocking me from running my code it seems to be within line 126 of my code. I am basically trying to retrieve multiple submetrics to combine into a main metricid but I am not sure how to solve this error. I have thought about merging the separate values shown below so they would match the id figure but I am not sure how to achieve that. The aim of this script is to retrieve information from a url that would be then identified by a metricid and the information further identified by a submetric id of which there are three show in the s1id variable in the code snippet. I have also attached the url to demonstrate what I am trying to use my code to retrieve from. The error occurs around the for loop with ids and the s1id variables and I am unsure of how to solve this and it gives the error above in the title`     'NVQ3 only 16-64': 'https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_17_5.data.csv?geography=1925185537,1925185538,1925185540...1925185542,1925185572,1925185570,1925185545,1925185547,1925185548,1925185569,1925185552,1925185554,1925185556,1925185562,1925185573,1925185563...1925185567,1925185578...1925185581,1925185583,1925185586...1925185597,2092957697...2092957703,1811939329...1811939332,1811939334...1811939336,1811939338...1811939428,1811939436...1811939442,1811939768,1811939769,1811939443...1811939497,1811939499...1811939501,1811939503,1811939505...1811939507,1811939509...1811939517,1811939519,1811939520,1811939524...1811939570,1811939575...1811939599,1811939601...1811939628,1811939630...1811939634,1811939636...1811939647,1811939649,1811939655...1811939664,1811939667...1811939680,1811939682,1811939683,1811939685,1811939687...1811939704,1811939707,1811939708,1811939710,1811939712...1811939717,1811939719,1811939720,1811939722...1811939730,1807745025...1807745028,1807745030...1807745032,1807745034...1807745083,1807745085,1807745282,1807745283,1807745086...1807745155,1807745157...1807745164,1807745166...1807745170,1807745172...1807745177,1807745179...1807745194,1807745196,1807745197,1807745199,1807745201...1807745218,1807745221,1807745222,1807745224,1807745226...1807745231,1807745233,1807745234,1807745236...1807745244,1853882369...1853882372,1853882374...1853882379&date=latestMINUS2-latest&variable=299&measures=20599,21001,21002,21003', }

```
valueid = helpers.getNewValueid(cursor)

master = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['metricid', 'value', 'submetric_1id', 'submetric_2id', 'submetric_3id', 'geoid', 'year'])

no_more_data = 0

for link, ids in zip(urls.items(), metricids.items()):

    # convert items to the value not a list of the key and value
    link = link[1]
    ids = ids[1]

    r = requests.get(link)
    numBytes += len(r.content)

    print('Data read from %s" % link')
    logging.info("Data read from %s" % link)

    data = r.content.decode("utf8")
    csv_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))

    latestDate = helpers.getLatestDateMetric(cursor, ids, searchQuarter=False, searchMonth=False, searchWeek=False,
                                             searchDay=False)[0]

    '''Section 3: Process the data to form a master dataframe'''

    #converting the date column in the csv to datetime so max() will work properly
    csv_df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(csv_df["DATE"])

    #extracting just the year to match the latestDate variable in comparison
    csv_df["DATE"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(csv_df["DATE"]).year

    if csv_df["DATE"].max() > latestDate:
        '''in master dataframe we need these columns:
            -valueid (insert later)
            -metricid (use helper)
            -value
            -submet 1ID(insert)
            -submet 2ID(Nan)
            -submet 3ID (Nan)
            -Geoid
            -year'''

    csv_df = csv_df[csv_df['DATE'] > latestDate]

    
    if ids == 267:
        s1id = 1808, 1809, 1810
    else:
        s1id = np.nan

    serve = pd.DataFrame({
        'metricid': ids,
        'value': csv_df['OBS_VALUE'],
        'submetric_1id': s1id,
        'submetric_2id': np.nan,
        'submetric_3id': np.nan,
        'year': csv_df['DATE'],
        'geoid': csv_df['GEOGRAPHY_CODE']

    })

    master = master.append(serve)

    if len(csv_df) == 0:
        logging.error("Master DF empty but new year is empty but new date is avaliable. check your source")
        raise ValueError('Master DF is empty but a new year is available from datasource. check your code')

else:
    no_more_data += 1

if no_more_data >= 2:
    endTime = time.time()
    logging.info('Took %s s and downloaded %s bytes (%s)' % (endTime - startTime, numBytes,
                                                             helpers.bytesConversion(numBytes)))
    print('Took %s and downloaded %s bytes (%s).' % (endTime - startTime, numBytes,
                                                     helpers.bytesConversion(numBytes)))

    return [True, 0, endTime - startTime, numBytes]
else:

    '''Section 4: Constructing database tables'''

    master.insert(0, 'valueid', range(valueid, valueid + len(master)))

    value = pd.DataFrame({
        'valueid': master['valueid'],
        'metricid': master['metricid'],
        'value': master['value'],
        'submetric_1id': master['submetric_1id'],
        'submetric_2id': master['submetric_2id'],
        'submetric_3id': master['submetric_3id'],
    })

geo_value = pd.DataFrame({
    'geoid': master['geoid'],
    'valueid': master['valueid']
})

year_master = master[master['year'].notnull()]
year = pd.DataFrame({
    'valueid': year_master['valueid'],
    'year': year_master['year']
})

print(master.to_string(index=False))

if outputMode == 'sql':
    helpers.checkMasterForUploadErrors((master, ip, port, dummyUploadDatabase))

    engine = create_engine(
        'postgresql+psycopg2://' + userID + ':' + password + '@' + ip + ':' + port + '/' + database)

    print("uploading value table...")
    value.to_sql("value", engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
    print("uploading geo_value table...")
    geo_value.to_sql("geo_value", engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
    print("uploading year table...")
    year.to_sql("year", engine, if_exists="append", index=False)

elif outputMode == 'csv':
    print("outputting value to csv...")
    value.to_csv("value.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")
    print("outputting geo_value to csv...")
    geo_value.to_csv("geo_value.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")
    print("outputting sub1 to csv...")
    year.to_csv("year.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8-sig")

endTime = time.time()
logging.info('Took %s s and downloaded %s bytes (%s)' % (endTime - startTime, numBytes,
                                                         helpers.bytesConversion(numBytes)))
print('Took %s s and downloaded %s bytes (%s)' % (endTime - startTime, numBytes,
                                                  helpers.bytesConversion(numBytes)))
return [True, len(master), endTime - startTime, numBytes]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a fix to the problem you have posted. It is not very clear, at least to me. This i more a pointer to what you could try which is more **pandorable**.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io 

url = 'https://www.nomisweb.co.uk/api/v01/dataset/NM_17_5.data.csv'
s = requests.get(url).content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode("utf-8")))

df.head()
```

The above code snipped will load the data from the url into a dataframe and perhaps all the transformation you intend to do can be done the data frame.